# Error : cron job has not been configured yet

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, installation, component-manager

I am running Magento 2.1.0 on Lamp-Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0.8.

I am getting an error while installing a new theme using *system > web setup wizard > component manager*.

In the readiness check process I am getting the following errors:

```
Cron script readiness check failed. 

Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
Other checks will fail as a result (PHP version, PHP settings, and PHP extensions)

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
```

I had created a cron job, not sure I have done it correctly (I am newbie in Linux platform). Here is how I created the cron job:

#### In terminal:

```
crontab -u user -e
```

and then I added the following contents:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/ecommerce/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/ecommerce/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/ecommerce/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/ecommerce/var/log/update.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/ecommerce/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/ecommerce/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

I got this from official Magento documentation, I changed the php and magento directory according to my setup.

But I am still getting this error. How can I check whether those jobs are running?

Is there anything else I should do?  Should I create any files ?

I added the following job below those 3 jobs for testing purpose

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/ecommerce/testcron/testcron.php >> /var/www/html/ecommerce/testcron/cron.out
```

#### testcron.php:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello " ;
?>
```

`cron.out` file was working fine (showing the text hello).

So whats the problem with those 3 jobs?

Comment: 1] First of all try to access your cronjob file using URL 2] Set it for 1 second or 1 minute for Increment Count/Send Mail, etc.. 3] Still not work then check for server support.

Comment: @AnkitShah Thanks for the reply, I tried to access those files via URL(/var/log/setup.cron.log, update.cron.log, magento.cron.log, update/cron.php) but it gives 403 forbidden error with the message 'you dont have permission to access /path/file on this server'. How can I set permission?

Comment: Only u need to check testcron.php & for other log files u can't access via URL, u can open in your editor

Comment: @AnkitShah It will be helpful if you can explain in detail about the 2nd step you suggested. I am new to linux

Comment: @AnkitShah everything is fine with testcron.php, but those log files( setup.cron.log, update.cron.log, magento.cron.log) doesn't exist in /var/log folder.

Comment: Go to command line & locate your magento folder. On shell write `vi <filename>` http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/

Comment: you can try to visit this site for further documentations using ssh commands. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the permissions of var folder and its subfolder to 777 by using

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

Hope this will help someone new to ubuntu and magento

Comment: You should never use 777 permissions, although if it's only on your own system it's probably OK. The problem might have been ownership, not permissions, not sure. Look at our [file system permissions and ownership](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-set-two-users) page again and see if it helps.

Answer (score 7):

I went into {magento-directory}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php

around Line 194

i commented out :

```
 //$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
 //$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();
```

and replaced it with :

```
$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];
```

this just skips the Cron check altogether.